# How to execute different query based on the result got from executing query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, birt

My Question is:

If I retrieve data from one table ...say **select id from table**.

Based on the result of **id,**

I need to execute different queries say,

If id=1 then **select * from table1**,

If id=2 the **select * from table2** and

If id=3, then **select * from table3**

How to achieve this in MySQL database or in Birt report?

Please give me an example or syntax for this.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: does this all need to be in one sql statement?

Comment: @Randy Yes if possible or in stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I have understood from your question, this is the best solution I can think of. 
Use Union like this.

```
 SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT id,name FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id,name FROM table2
UNION
SELECT id,name FROM table3
) num
WHERE num.id = ?
```

you can use this query for Birt report
so what ever id you pass, result will be generated based on that id
Hope it will Solve your purpose.
Regards